# How do I send messages on a timer with websockets

Tags: node.js

I have the following node.js code

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const db = require('./db')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({port: 5000});

wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("New Client Connected!");

    ws.on("message", data => {
        console.log(data);

        let interval = setInterval(()=> getSelPos(ws), 2000);
    });

    ws.on("close", () => {
        console.log("Client has Disconnected");
    });
});

const getSelPos = async(ws) =>{
    try {
        const result = await db.pool.query("select value from db.tags where tag in ('1006', '1004', '1002')");
        ws.send({selector: result[2].value.toString(), pressure: result[1].value.toString(), temperature: result[0].value.toString()});
        console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

My intention is to perform an initial handshake with my React code, then once a message is received from React (a confirmation of the connection opening), I start a 2 second interval to send database updates to my react component data. However this code currently doesn't work. I'm not sure how to fix it now. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is my code on the other end for testing purposes currently:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000");
ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
  console.log("We are connected!");
  ws.send("Hello!");
});

ws.addEventListener("message", ({data}) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

EDIT 2:

Console output I got was:

```
    New Client Connected!
<Buffer 48 65 6c 6c 6f 21>
(node:16492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object
    at Function.from (buffer.js:330:9)
    at toBuffer (my-path\node_modules\ws\lib\buffer-util.js:95:18)
    at Sender.send (my-path\node_modules\ws\lib\sender.js:270:17)
    at WebSocket.send (my-path\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:423:18)
    at getSelPos (my-path\server.js:22:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16492) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Who is sendng the first data `ws.on("message" ...` it seems like `ws.send({selector: ...` this piece of code in `getSelPos`, however getSelPos will only be called if you receive the message. Seems to me like a chicken or the egg problem!

Comment: @AnuragVohra this code is triggered when the node server receives a message from react. So I'm sending "Connected!" from React, which then triggers the 2 second interval.

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting. Could you please edit your answer to tell what's happening right now?

Comment: Well, the error seems pretty obvious: "ReferenceError: ws is not defined" You're trying to use the `ws` argument to the callback in `getSelPos`, a completely different function. Pass the reference to that function (i.e., make it `getSelPos(ws)` and `getSelPos = async (ws) =>`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Did this but got a new error. Updated my post

Comment: If you get a new error, that's a new question, especially when you get an answer. Basically you're disrespecting akshayks' work in creating that answer by changing your question and making it look like they were answering something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error, it seems like you are using the socket instance `ws` in your `getSelPos` function but the function doesn't have access to it. Pass the instance to the function when you call it and it should work:

```
wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("New Client Connected!");

    ws.on("message", data => {
        console.log(data);

        let interval = setInterval(()=> getSelPos(ws), 2000);
    });
    // rest of the function
});

const getSelPos = async(ws) =>{
    // Use socket instance
}
```

Comment: Updated my post with a new error

Comment: @Cm1602 Use `data` as argument instead of `{data}`